# Sphinx:Search:How to index and find words with separator "-"

Tags: full-text-search, sphinx

Can't index and find words such as 'N-7' and etc. by sphinx.
Directives "charset_table", symbols was added - but not working.

What else to do?

Sphinx 2.2.10 config

```
index site
{
        charset_table = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, -, a..z, \
        U+410..U+42F->U+430..U+44F, U+430..U+44F, U+401->U+451, U+451, U+2D

        type = rt
        path = /var/lib/sphinx/site
        ondisk_attrs=1
        morphology = lemmatize_ru_all, lemmatize_en_all, lemmatize_de_all, stem_enru
        prefix_fields = title
        infix_fields=
        min_prefix_len = 2
        expand_keywords = 1
        min_word_len = 3
        stopwords = /etc/sphinx/stopwords.txt
}
```

Vladimir.

Comment: Did you delete the index (even with `truncate`) after changing the config, and *re*insert the data? Just changing the config won't update existing documents.

Comment: Site-engine based on Bitrix.
After config changes i'm restarting searchd.service and run full reindex all site in admin section.

Or did you mean to delete all *.lock/meta/ram/etc files in /var/lib/sphinx/ before starting searchd and full reindex site?

Comment: Not familar with bitrix to know what its 'full reindex' actully does. But shutting down searchd, deleting those files (and the binlog!) and restarting searchd will definitly clear the existing index. You then might be able to use that command to reinsert all data?

Comment: Sorry for delay - i'm testing on developer's site, then do the same on production site.

All works!